# Apache NiFi: Remove Username and Password login by default on UI

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

I'm currently working on setting up NiFi, I've noticed as a part of the [Version 1.14.0](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.14.0) release, by default we have security features enabled which requires a username and password to access the UI. For my specific Use Case, I don't want this. Where and how would I have this disabled on start up so it's behaves similar to older versions of NiFi?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As of 1.14.0, NiFi is now secure by default. Disabling this is not advised.

The initial user/pass is auto-generated and printed in nifi-app.log when you first start NiFi.

If you want to disable it, you'll need to reconfigure NiFi to take out the single user auth. Take a look in `login-identity-providers.xml` and `nifi.properies`.

[Here](https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/07/19/apache-nifi-1-14-0-secure-by-default) and [here](https://exceptionfactory.com/posts/2021/07/21/single-user-access-and-https-in-apache-nifi/) are good sources of information.

Answer (score 0):

In windows also, run the command nifi.sh single user credentials and DONT forget to restart to get credentials be effected – it wont ask for login.. by default!